# N-queens backtrack not working for n=9 and higher

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking, n-queens

I've been practicing the standard recusion and backtracking examples online, and came across the N-queens problem (in the LeetCode setting).
After a lot of tinkering, I managed to apply a recursion in order to retrieve ANY, not all, solutions for a given board size n.

However, my algorithm works up to n=8, printing out valid board configurations, but invalid ones when n=9 or equal to the few higher numbers I tried. Invalid meaning that some board rows are full of dots and not populated by a "Q" queen, but the backtracking fails to catch that, possibly due to a buggy recursion.

For example, for n=9, this is the output:

```
testing backtrack
['Q........', '..Q......', '....Q....', '.Q.......', '...Q.....', '........Q', '.........', '.........', '.........']

testing backtrack
['..Q......', 'Q........', '...Q.....', '.Q.......', '....Q....', '........Q', '.........', '.........', '.........']

testing backtrack
['.Q.......', '...Q.....', 'Q........', '..Q......', '....Q....', '........Q', '.........', '.........', '.........']

testing backtrack
['.Q.......', '...Q.....', '.....Q...', 'Q........', '..Q......', '....Q....', '......Q..', '.........', '.........']

testing backtrack
['.Q.......', '....Q....', '......Q..', '...Q.....', 'Q........', '..Q......', '.....Q...', '.........', '.........']

testing backtrack
['.Q.......', '...Q.....', '.....Q...', '.......Q.', '..Q......', 'Q........', '......Q..', '....Q....', '.........']

testing backtrack
['.Q.......', '...Q.....', '.....Q...', '..Q......', '....Q....', '.........', 'Q........', '.........', '......Q..']

testing backtrack
['.Q.......', '...Q.....', '......Q..', '..Q......', '.......Q.', '.....Q...', '.........', 'Q........', '....Q....']

testing backtrack
['.Q.......', '...Q.....', '.....Q...', '..Q......', '........Q', '.........', '....Q....', '.......Q.', 'Q........']
```

and you can see that in all cases, at least one row in the board seems not populated by a Queen.

Can anyone pinpoint to me where the backtracking may be failing in the algorithm below?
Thank you in advance!

```python
    class Solution:
      def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.board =  ["."*n] * n
        self.n_queens = n    
        self.queenPos = []
    
      def solveNQueens(self, n: int) -> list[list[str]]:
    
        def changeLetter(letter, i,j):
          # change letter in board
          s = list(self.board[i])
          s[j] = letter
          self.board[i] = "".join(s)
          if letter == "Q":
            self.queenPos.append([i,j])
          else:
            self.queenPos.pop()
    
        def boardOk(k,l):
          # print(self.queenPos)
          def check_attack(piece_1, piece_2):
            # check if they are in the same row
            if piece_1[0] == piece_2[0]:
                return True
            # check if they are in the same column
            elif piece_1[1] == piece_2[1]:
                return True
            # check if they are in the same diagonal
            elif abs(piece_1[0] - piece_2[0]) == abs(piece_1[1] - piece_2[1]):
                return True
            else:
                # print("queens are not attacking in diagonal")
                return False
          
          if len(self.queenPos)>0:
            # print(self.queenPos)
            for pos in self.queenPos:
              if check_attack([k,l], pos):
                return False
    
          return True
    
        def backtrack(numQueens, i, j):
          
          if boardOk(i,j):
              changeLetter("Q", i,j)
              self.n_queens-=1
          else:
            return
          
          if self.n_queens<=0:
            return
                    
          for k in range(n):
            for l in range(n):
              backtrack(self.n_queens, k, l)
          
        i=0
        while self.n_queens!=0:
          print(f"\ntesting backtrack")
          # print(f"\ti={i}")
          self.board =  ["."*n] * n
          self.n_queens = n
          self.queenPos = []
          backtrack(n, i, 0) # this works for all cases except 9 instead of backtrack(n,0,i) which doesn't except for 4
          print(self.board)
          if i+1<n :
            i+=1 
          else:
            break  
    
        return
    
    if __name__=="__main__":
        n=9
        sol = Solution()
        sol.solveNQueens(n)
```

Comment: Apologies. Fails to work in this case means that the board configuration returned is not valid, and more specifically that for some reason the board is not filled with the entirety of the n available queens, rather some rows are left unfilled and the algorithm doesn't manage to catch that condition.

This is visible in the output 'testing backtrack' lines during execution.

Comment: Actually, I will include them all in the description.

Comment: While this isn't necessarily the direct, functional cause of the error, one thing making the code extremely difficult to debug is the variable usage (scopes and naming). The class does not take 'n' as an input parameter, but copies a global (`self.n_queens = n`) to define an instance variable, and a shadowed-name n is passed to the solve function. Then the solver method modifies self.n_queens in an outer loop, passes n as a parameter to backtrack() as numQueens, which is unused; meanwhile backtrack modifies self.n_queens while also using `n`. It's unclear that this program even halts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, forget my comments. I thought the diagonal test was wrong, I just thought you applied a different idea wrongly, but the idea you applied was correct.

Your actual problem is that you are not backtracking correctly: You just try the first position for each Queen, and only retry placing the first one. `backtrack` needs to actually backtrack, e.g. erase it's changes:

```
        def backtrack(numQueens, i, j):
          
          if boardOk(i,j):
              changeLetter("Q", i,j)
              self.n_queens-=1
          else:
            return False # This is failing
          
          if self.n_queens == 0:
            return True # We found a solution
                    
          for k in range(n):
            for l in range(n):
              if backtrack(self.n_queens, k, l):
                  return True # We found a solution
          changeLetter(".", i, j) # Remove the Queen we tried from the board.
          self.n_queens += 1
          return False # None of the tries for other Queens works
```

and the while loop inside solution can be a for loop:

```
        self.board =  ["." * n] * n # You don't need to reset these each loop. backtrack cleans up behind it.
        self.n_queens = n
        self.queenPos = []
        for i in range(n):
          if backtrack(n, i, 0):
            print(self.board)
            return self.board
        else:
            raise ValueError("We did not find a solution")
```

Comment: Many thanks for this! This is the answer I was looking for.